# making a switch

Tags: switches

I am working on circuit, I need to make a switch. What I want it to do is; when the circuit is at 4 volts it goes somewhere and when it is 6 volts it goes somewhere else. I think 
I can use a BJT but how?

Comment: This question is very vague.  I have questions like: What is "It" - the current? Can you describe (possibly with a schematic) the circuit which you're getting your signal from and the circuit to which you're directing your output?  How fast does this all need to happen?  What if the input is 3.5V, 5V, or 6.5V?  etc.

Comment: Please try to clean this question up.  Right now, we can only guess at what kinds of answers will help you.

Comment: are you saying that you need to basically *make* a comparator with transistors?  You can't just pop in an IC that does this switching for you?

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow.  What is it you are trying to switch?  It makes no sense to say "the circuit" is at 4 volts.  Some node may be at 4V, but a circuit has multiple nodes.  And what is the "it" that has to go somewhere or somehwere else?

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt would be to use a comparator like an LM139:

[image]

The output will swing to logic high or low, depending upon what Vin is relative to Vref.  You would set Vref in your case to 5V.

Comment: I need switch to connect and disconnect between a device in my circuit.
The microcontroller will control it with a 3.3 v signal. there will be batteries, it would range between 4 and 6 volts.

Comment: @Fouad we need more info.  What are you trying to disconnect?  Power?  Data bus?  Address bus?  Is it a high-power device?  So the device is powered by batteries, whose output can range between 4 and 6V?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is a SPDT (single pole, dual throw) relay. You use a comparator to compare the input voltage with 5V. If it's higher (6V) the output is high and you switch the relay on. If it's lower than 5V (4V) the output is low and the relay will be off. You'll probably need a transistor to drive the relay.

[image]

Comment: or he can use an SSR instead of a mechanical relay, and skip the transistor.

Comment: @Dave - I've never seen a SPDT SSR, I'm afraid they're all SPST (single pole, single throw). Also, the electromechanical relay is more versatile with respect to load; you can switch either power or signals, AC or DC (OP isn't clear about this).

Comment: AH!  My mistake, I completely missed the SPDT even though it was right there in front of my face.